# Python syntax error?? (except ValueError)

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, except

Code:

```
def is_num(num1):
    try:
        int(num1)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Consol Output:

```
 except ValueError:
     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I started python about 5 days ago so I don't relly understand the error or how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: I got this syntax error when i run it and i dont know why

Comment: The code you posted here is valid Python code. Are you 100% certain there is no other code or that your indentations are correct (tabs vs spaces)?

Comment: I notice your original source as pasted uses tabs, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to indent the function body 
This is working :

```
def Foo():
    try:
        raise Exception("error")
    except Exception :
        print "test"
```